# 404 для разных страниц

Tags: http-status-code-404, apache, php, .htaccess

Как сделать так, чтобы у меня выдавалась разная ошибка 404 в разных случаях... Я не знаю, как правильно сформулировать вопрос, но мне надо так, чтобы в таких случаях:

- mysite.ru/**client**/erunda.php
- mysite.ru/**client**/tozhe_erunda.php
- mysite.ru/**client**/tozhe_erunda/tolko_drugaya.php

Мне показывалась страница, находящаяся в mysite.ru/**client**/404.php, а в остальных -- mysite.ru/404.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было просто положить в папку `client` файл `.htaccess` со своими параметрами. И все прекрасно будет работать

Comment: А если такой папки нет?

Comment: Обработать запрос принимающим скриптом